# How Can I convert NSMutableDictionary object into JSON format in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I have a NSMutableDictionary object that returns data like as follows

```
Key : ClassObject
```

I want to convert that into a JSON format. For example

```
{
1:{id:1,name:'aa',class='1'}
}
```

I am using CJSONSerializer.  But when I do

```
NSData *jsonData = [[CJSONSerializer serializer] serializeObject:dictionary error:&error];
```

It returning 'Nil'. Please suggest me how can I convert it into a JSON format.

Comment: It's returning `nil` because that's not valid JSON

Comment: After that call, try `NSLog`ing `error` to see what the problem is.

Comment: worthy to note: there is native JSON serialization/deserialization with NSJSONSerialization. There is no point to use third party code for this, except to expose yourself to potential bugs

Comment: What did the error message say when you dumped it?  (That's why that error parameter is there, you know.)

Comment: Visit json.org to see what valid JSON looks like.  Then all you need to do is construct a "nest" of NSArrays and NSDictionarys and run it through NSJSONSerialization or one of the other JSON kits to produce the JSON string.  But note that the arrays/dictionaries must have contents legal for JSON -- only strings, NSNumbers, and other arrays and dictionaries -- no other objects.

Answer (score 0):

You JSON structure is not valid. It should look like this:

```
{
    "1": {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "aa",
        "class": "1"
    }
}
```

To validate a JSON use this [online tool.](http://jsonlint.com)

Comment: he isn't asking about his json structure. he is asking how to convert an object to json. The "json" he gave is an example of what he wants only.